# Decide if subspace or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, vector-fields

We have given the field $K$ and set $M$ and the $K$-vector space $V = \text{Abb}(M,K)$ (where $\text{Abb}(M,K)$ are all the maps from $M$ to $K$). Decide if the following sets $U$ are subspaces ($N\subset M$):

> $$U = \{f\in \text{Abb}(M,K) : f(m) =0 ~\forall~ m \in M\setminus N\}$$

I tried to approach the problems with the subspace criteria, i.e. for all $f,g\in U$ and $\lambda \in K$ we have to have $f\circ g \in U$ and $\lambda \cdot f \in U$. However, I was not able to make any progress with this approach.

**My approach for a:** So I pick $f,g\in U$ and now I have to show that $f\circ g \in U$. But here I don't see how to continue. Also, I have to show that $\lambda \cdot f \in U$.

Comment: Perhaps pick one part and show your work/where you got stuck.

Comment: Ok, I will add something

Comment: Does the composition make sense?  How is it defined if both $f$ and $g$ are from $M$ to $K$?  Are you using the right operation?

Comment: Show us how the addition and scalar multiplication on $\text{Abb}(M,K)$ are defined.